# Easiest way to draw line graphs with Google API

Tags: bash, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have datum in a CSV file, that I would like to be graphed by the use of Google Charts. I've done [some research](http://visual.yantrajaal.com/2013/12/google-charts-from-public-csv-datasets.html), and concluded the best way of doing it would be:

1. Upload the CSV file online from the server to Quandl
2. Download contents of the CSV file in to a HTML template

This will all be done with a Crontab, so the graphs will be updated in intervals - ie automatically.

**Q1:** Is there any other known alternatives of converting contents of a CSV file to a Google Charts

**Q2:** Can this be done with BASH? Or is there a more appropriate/easier languages for such a project [ie Python, JS?].

This generated graph will be embedded into a website, and thus be online.

Comment: Why do you need "Google Charts"? There are many ways to make charts programmatically, e.g., gnuplot, matplotlib, just to name two.

Comment: By the way, the choice of the scripting language here is largely irrelevant. You just need appropriate tooling.

Comment: @4ae1e1 google charts, as I will be embedding this graph to a website later on. As for what language to use - I am fairly new to coding, never done an automated graph such as this, perhaps a language would be more advantageous then another.

Answer (score 0):

From Google Chart docs:

> The most common way to use Google Charts is with simple JavaScript
>   that you embed in your web page. You load some Google Chart libraries,
>   list the data to be charted, select options to customize your chart,
>   and finally create a chart object with an id that you choose. Then,
>   later in the web page, you create a  with that id to display the
>   Google Chart.

Then, the most *common* language is javascript, why are you trying something different?